# Composer fails to download PHP Codesniffer to plugin

Tags: composer

I am getting an error when trying to install the `squizlabs/php_codesniffer` package via composer into my WordPress plugin.

I am using Flywheel for the local server, with composer 1.8.6 installed globally at `/usr/local/bin/composer.phar`

I have also tried using the composer file locally in the plugin folder, but I still get the same error. This is the command I run while in the plugin directory

`composer require --dev squizlabs/php_codesniffer`

[image]

Comment: Should this question rather be on the main stack overflow site?  or is it fine here?

Comment: Yes, better on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also better put the error message in a blockquote. Screenshots are a pain to read. Especially on mobile.

Comment: @Warwick I guess you need to update OpenSSL.

Comment: Found this: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/6870

Comment: Thanks,  will try out all of these suggestions.   Updating OpenSSL sounds like a good plan.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the error by updating openssl as @Sally Cj  said.  I was still using Mac OS El Capitan,  so I tried the [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) method of updating it,  but that didnt fix it.

I eventually ended up just upgrading to the latest "Mojave" OS version, and it works 100% now.

[image]